# Operation in a multiprocessing queue hanging when given certain tasks to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, message-queue, python-multiprocessing

I have a pair of tiny Python modules. One is [`datafy`](https://github.com/ResidentMario/datafy), a module for reading in references to data of various formats. The other is [`limited-process`](https://github.com/ResidentMario/limited-process), a module for calling some function in Python with a timeout in case it takes too long.

`limited-process` is a very simple `multiprocessing` wrapper:

```
def limited_get(uri, q, timeout=60,
                callback=lambda uri: uri,
                **kwargs):
    p = mp.Process(target=callback, args=(uri, q, kwargs))
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout)
    p.terminate()
    # If the process succeeded the exitcode is 0.
    return q.get() if p.exitcode == 0 else None
```

What I would like to do is use the one with the other: wrap a `datafy.get` in a `limited_process` in order to keep it running within a certain threshold of time.

I am using it like so:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
limited_process.limited_get(
            uri,
            mp.Queue(),
            callback=lambda uri, q, kwargs: q.put(datafy.get(uri, **kwargs)),
            timeout=10)
```

However, what I am finding is that this function works in certain cases, but not in others. When I pass it [this URL](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD), everything works as I expect it to. However, when I pass it [this one](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/q68s-8qxv/files/511dbe78-65f3-470f-9cc8-c1415f75a6e6?filename=AnnAvg1_7_300mSurfaces.zip), the process hangs.

The difference is that while the first download is a CSV file, the second is in an archival format. `datafy` treats these differently ([source](https://github.com/ResidentMario/datafy/blob/master/datafy/datafy.py)), performing a lot of filesystem stuff in the latter case.

Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here? I am beginning to wonder whether or not I doing things that are not "allowed" while inside of a process in the latter case, but not in the former.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: No, the latest Ubuntu 16.